# which event to create for record creation after opportunity creation?

Tags: trigger

Which trigger and event to create for custom record creation AFTER opportunity record creation? Please give reasons too.
will it be after insert trigger? this is my gut feeling.
Please give reasons

Comment: After insert trigger. All the required info such as opportunity ID is available in after trigger., If the record creation requires this info

Comment: plz give reasons

Comment: May i know what is the Object Name. Just to know whether it is standard object or Custom object?

Comment: its a custom object

Comment: This question does not seem at all unclear. It may not show much research, but it is very clear what is being asked. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Process builder :-)

Answer (score 5):

The documentation on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) states:

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

You are not doing anything recommended in the `before` guidelines. A couple `after` points:

- You need the record's Id to create child records.
- If you are performing any `DML Operation`, `after` is recommended.

So, if you want to create related records when creating an `Opportunity` record (inserting it into the database), use the `after insert` event. Note that `Process Builder` may (depending on the complexity of your task) allow you to achieve this functionality in a declarative way without writing a single `Apex Trigger` or line of code.